# I can't figure out how to convert this from C# to Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I know a little C#, but no JavaScript. What is wrong with this code?

```
function OnCollisionEnter(Collision target) {
    if (target.gameObject.name == "InstantBullet") {
        OnDamage();
        DestroyObject(target.gameObject);
    }
}
```

It says something is wrong with `target`.

Comment: You should check, first, whether target is null.

Comment: Javascript doesn't use types the way C# does, try: OnCollisionEnter(target)

Comment: You can't just convert from C# to JavaScript? They are **completely** different languages with **completely** different jobs and synax

Comment: Is this for the upcoming release of Duke Nukem Forever 2?

Comment: You need to learn Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

You do not specify the type of the parameter in JavaScript, like you do in C#.

Try this:

```
function OnCollisionEnter(target){
    if (target.gameObject.name == "InstantBullet"){
        OnDamage();
        DestroyObject(target.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Note: This assumes that `target` has an expando property named `gameObject`.

Answer (score 4):

The only visible problem is that you have a type definition for `target` on your function signature. This is not valid for javascript. Change your function to this.

```
function OnCollisionEnter(target){
    if (target.gameObject.name == "InstantBullet"){
        OnDamage();
        DestroyObject(target.gameObject);
    }
 }
```